# How to compute the weights gradients for Convolutional RBM with CD?

Tags: train, restricted-boltzmann-machine, convolution

I've successfully implemented a RBM and trained it with CD-k, but I now have some issues doing the same with Convolutional RBM.

The visible and hidden biases gradients are easy to compute: v1 - v2 for visible bias and h1_k - h2_k for the hidden bias. But I failed to see how to compute the gradients for the weights. The weights are NH x NH matrices. In RBM it was easy since the weight matrix was NH * NV dimension and with multiplication of h1 * v1 - h2 * v2 we could have the gradients, but the dimension are not equivalent in CRBM.

What is the rule to compute the gradients ? Or is there a different way to update the weights ? It's probably a convolution, but I fail to see how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradients can be computed from this formula:

$$
W_{pos} = V_1 *_v \tilde{H_1} \\
W_{neg} = V_2 *_v \tilde{H_2} \\
W_{grad} = W_{pos} - W_{neg}
$$

$*_v$ being a "valid* convolution. $\tilde{H}$ being $H$ flipped horizontally and vertically.